# DAX - get category by matching column from two tables

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a table with column 'Product' and Lookup table with 'Product Description' and 'Category' columns as follows:

```
    TableMain
    ('Product')
    "Bike"
    "Sport-100 Helmet"

    Lookup
    ('Product Description','Category')
    "4-Bike", "Bike"
    "Sport-100 Helmet, Black", "Helmets"
```

I need a calculated column 'Category' in TableMain by matching TableMain.'Product' and Lookup.'Product Description' and getting the Category. as follows:

```
    TableMain
    ('Product', 'Category')
    "Bike", "Bike"
    "Sport-100 Helmet", "Helmets"
```

Please suggest a DAX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed to come up with following DAX but it runs forever for 10 Million rows(in thousands ok):

`=CALCULATE(
    LASTNONBLANK( Lookup[Category],1) ,
    FILTER(
        Lookup,
      SEARCH(MainTable[Product],Lookup[Product Description],1,0) > 0))`

Can someone please suggest an optimization?

Comment: Prakash, your best bet is to re write your question in an easier to understand way. If you do, someone will help!

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but the question is clear. I do not think it can be written in more clear way.

Comment: Trust me, the question wasn't clear - the formatting helps. You aren't going to solve this with DAX - your two tables don't appear to have a common column.

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved using CHARINDEX in SQL.

Thanks